# Pulling data from multiple databases on different db connections with a common target table

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, database-design, database-connection

think of this scenario..

We have a web service that communicates with and pulls data from multiple, say 5, 6 or even 10K, databases. Each database has its very own design, tables and columns but they all implement a "Users" table. Our web service must look in each of those "Users" tables and access their data.

Question is, how to manage such number of database connections/contexts taking into account the different names of the "Users" table and its columns' in each DB.

Comment: Master data management is an answer, eg Master Data Services for sql server. However, if you know that this will be the only table that need synchronizing ten maybe a custom solution basen on linked server connections would be more in place.